# Receiving errors when trying compile Java from command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, javac

I'm trying to wean myself from IDEs -- getting to be lazy as a programmer. Before posting, I looked at these sites and it didn't help:

[Error compiling Java from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014505/error-compiling-java-from-command-line)
[Compiling java from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940660/compiling-java-from-the-command-line) 
[Javac "cannot find symbol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537668/javac-cannot-find-symbol)
http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-ides/16906-trouble-running-java-file-windows-command-prompt.html#post71916

I have the following path to my source files:

D:\workspace\HelloWorld\src\com\dogzilla

There are two files in that path: Start.java...

```
package com.dogzilla;

public class Start{

    public Start() {

    }

    private static final String S = "Hello World";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        hw.printHelloWorld(S);
    }

}
```

...and HelloWorld.java

```
package com.dogzilla;

public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    public void printHelloWorld(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

When I change the directory to `D:\workspace\HelloWorld\com\dogzilla\src\main\java` and run `javac Start.java`, it errors with:

```
Start.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        ^
  symbol:   class HelloWorld
  location: class Start
Start.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
                            ^
  symbol:   class HelloWorld
  location: class Start
2 errors
```

So I've read you have to specify the classpath because of the `package com.dogzilla;` line.

So I change the directory to `D:\workspace\HelloWorld` and run `javac -cp com\dogzilla\src\main\java\Start.java` (interestingly enough, the tab key completes the path so I know the command prompt is finding Start.java just fine) it errors with:

```
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

How can I compile and run this otherwise simple program?  The IDE hides this otherwise and I'm having problems learning it.

Comment: your missing the `import HelloWorld` in `Start` class ?

Comment: @tima... no it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @tonyhoan... why would I need to import?  HelloWorld?  I don't need to in an IDE... HW is in the same classpath and in the same package afterall.

Comment: @MGoBlue93 you have tried `javac Start.java HelloWorld.java`?

Comment: @tima... Yes, javac Start.java HelloWorld.java works.   I believe the problem, based upon previous reading, is due to my package statement.  The IDE handles that.  The CLI does not -- the user has to specify the parameters.  I'm clearly just not specifying the right thing.  When I try to run java Start, I get Error: Could not find or load main class Start.  When I try java -cp com.dogzilla Start or java -cp com.dogzilla.Start it fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to compile the java code into class files. The `javac` command is used for that.

You can run this command from anywhere, as long as you capture all of the java files that have to be compiled.

This will work:

```
[D:\workspace\HelloWorld\src]> javac com\dogzilla\*.java
```

this will also work:

```
[D:\workspace\HelloWorld\src\com\dogzilla] java Start.java HelloWorld.java
```

To run the compiled code, you use the `java` command. You have to use the fully qualified name of the main class so you have to be in the root source directory to do that.

```
[D:\workspace\HelloWorld\src]> java com.dogzilla.Start
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I had read previously that you need to do java -cp com.dogzilla Start.  Using java com.dogzilla.Start works instead!

Comment: @MGoBlue93 you can use `-cp` this way: `java -cp . com.dogzilla.Start`. Notice the dot which points to the current directory (src directory). `-cp` is used to specify the location of additional jars that are needed for your application, but you are not using any other jars so its not needed for now